# How to redirect with .htacces url with multiple variables

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need redirect from:

/index.php?option=com_rsticketspro&view=ticket&id=88888

to

/meus-tickets-sa/ver-ticket/88888

Answer (score 0):

Try and use this Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^meus-tickets-sa/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?option=com_rsticketspro&view=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.